# Browser problem for background-size property

Tags: css, blogger

I am using one picture as my background of header of my blog.
CSS i have  used is

```
#header-wrapper {
height:125px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0;
background: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_lxBSX0YJV58/TOspWPI1r-I/AAAAAAAAA34/uw872WFS3ME/s1600/headerbg.jpg") top center no-repeat;
background-size: 1120px 124px;
}
```

original width of an image is 990 px and  i made it 1120px using property

```
background-size: 1120px 124px;
```

It looks okay in firefox 4 and Opera 11 but doesn't work in IE 7, Palemoon etc. image size does not increases and remains 990 px.
You can check my blog [**HERE**](http://codehippo.blogspot.com)

Any help...how can i make it compatible with all browsers ?

Do i need to use another property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background-size` is a CSS3 property, and as such, it is not understood by ancient browsers. You might like [this post](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/), explaining various approaches to scaling background images.

Comment: so do u suggest an solution ?? any alternative ?? There should be a wa used by ancient browsers?

Comment: CSS background image sizing is impossible in earlier browsers. You will need to be creative. In your case, I'd just use an `<img>` tag. It can be scaled in all browsers, even without CSS whatsoever.

Comment: I am getting it..<img src="" width="" ../>..like this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making the original image the size you want.  Even if all browsers supported this CCS3 feature there is no telling what way they are going to implement it which may leave you with a distorted looking image.